How to fetch data with SSR in Next.js 14.1?
I am trying to fetch data to my dashboard component in SSR but get undefined
Are there any solution to fetch data properly?
Here is my code of Dashboard component:

import Container from "./Container";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authConfig } from "../../lib/auth";
import { getServer } from "@/app/api/servers";

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const session = await getServerSession(authConfig); // Wrap in getServerSession
  const userId = session?.user.id;

  const serverData = await getServer(userId); // Pass userId if needed
  return { props: { serverData } }; // Return object with serverData prop
};

const Dashboard = ({ serverData }) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full min-h-full p-4 border-b-2 border-t-2 border-t-white border-b-cyan-100 shadow-lg  mb-8 h-80 min-h-72">
      <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-row gap-5">
        <Container serverData={serverdata} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;

Here is the code of my getServer function:
export const getServer = async (userId: string) => {
  console.log("getServer", userId);
  try {
    // Find servers belonging to the user
    const servers = await prisma.server.findMany({
      where: {
        userId: userId,
      },
    });
    return servers;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors
    console.error("Error retrieving servers:", error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error for the caller to handle
  }
};



Just create async function to fetch data and call it in your Page.
const getData = async ()=> {
 return await getFromDb();
} 

const Dashboard = async () => {
 const data = await getData();

 return (<>{data.id}<>);
}


Next +13 doesn't support getServerSideProps as old versions.
If you don't use hooks like useState in your component or page, you can fetch data using server components like this:
"use server" // must be added at the top of the file
    
const Component = async ({ id }) => {
  const data = await getData(id);

  return <div>{data.name}</div>;
};

